# wget: regex does not match ampersand (&) in URL

Tags: regex, linux, wget

I am trying to download several URLs which contain following pattern,

`pagingSize=50&sorting=price_desc` with `--accept-regex` option.

*example* **code;**

```
wget --limit-rate=100k -m -nH -np -p -E -k -l 4 --accept-regex 'pagingSize=50' -r https://www.website.com/foo/bar
```

This downloads both

`bar?pagingSize=50.html` and

`bar?pagingSize=50&sorting=price_desc.html`.

I don't have any problem using regex `.*` ***unless*** extend it to contain character `&`, in order to download only the second one.

Unfortunately, trying all of the below options did not make it happen;

```
--accept-regex 'pagingSize.*sorting'
--accept-regex 'pagingSize=50.sorting'
--accept-regex 'pagingSize=50&sorting'
--accept-regex 'pagingSize=50\&sorting'
--accept-regex pagingSize=50\&sorting
```

Is there any way for `--accept-regex` to match `&`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, use `'pag[^&]*=50'` or something like that. ``'pag[^&]*=50[^0-9]'`` can work.

Comment: shouldn't it be like `'pagingSize=50[^&]*sorting'` @WiktorStribiżew ?

Comment: It will also match `pagingSize=500sorting`. Is it what you expect?

Comment: I actually want to escape `&` and match `pagingSize=50&sorting`. `&` is in URL link.

Comment: If you want the exact `pagingSize=50&sorting` string, there is nothing to escape. `&` is not any special regex metacharacter.